# Como fazer uma busca com Query Builder no Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Eu necessito exibir o nome do médico que solicitou um laudo de paciente, porem, com *Laravel* eu tentei mostrar esta informação na *View* assim:

```
{{laudo->paciente->medico->nome}}
```

Então eu recebia a mensagem de erro:

> Trying to get property of non-object

Como eu faço a consulta utilizando o *Query Builder* segundo o principio desta query:

```
select m.nome from medicos m, pacientes p, laudos l where m.id=p.medico_id and p.id=l.paciente_id and l.id=5;
```

> Classe *Medico*

```
class Medico extends Model{
   //    
    protected $fillable = [
        "nome", "crm", "email", "datanascimento", "senha"
    ];

    protected $table = 'medicos';

    public function pacientes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Paciente');
    }
}
```

> Classe *Paciente*

```
class Paciente extends Model{
//
    protected $fillable = [
        "medico_id", "nome", "rg", "email", "datanascimento", "senha"
    ];

    protected $table = 'pacientes';

    public function medico(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Medico', 'medico_id');
    }
    public function laudos(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Laudo');
    }
}
```

> Classe *Laudo*

```
class Laudo extends Model{
//
    protected $fillable = [
        "codigo", "paciente_id", "nome_arquivo", "data_emicao"
    ];

    protected $table = 'laudos';

    public function paciente(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Paciente', 'id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para exibir o nome do médico na view será necessário acessar o dado da segunte maneira:

```
{{$laudo->paciente["medico"]["nome"]}}
```

Os dados ficam armazenados em um array.

Answer (score 4):

Quando for carregar os laudos, utilize `Eager Loading`, o que irá carregar também registros de outras tabelas relacionadas:

```
$laudos = Laudo::with('paciente.medico')->get();
```

Fonte: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: Está retornando: "ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: No exemplo estou carregando uma collection de laudos. Caso queira retornar apenas um laudo, pode filtrar pelo id. 

Laudo::find($id)->with('paciente.medico');
ou
Laudo::where('id', $id)->with('paciente.medico')->first();